# The specific value cannot be parsed or is out of range when the attribute ApplyFormatInEditMode = true

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, razor, custom-data-attribute

I have an MVC application that uses entity framework and data annotations.  My model

```
  public partial class InstitutionBudget
{
    [Key]
  
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public int? Salaries1 { get; set; }
}
```

The razor page displays this value like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salaries1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control entry-item" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salaries1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
```

The controller retrieves the value correctly as 23000 but instead of getting 23,000 in the textbox I get a blank value.  the rendered HTML client is:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <input class="form-control entry-item text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Salaries1 must be a number." id="Salaries1" name="Salaries1" type="number" value="23,000">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Salaries1" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
```

I get an error message in the console:  The specified value "23,000" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.
If I remove ApplyFormatInEditMode = true from the attribute than the value is displayed 23000.  If I change the html to displayfor... it displays with the format 23,000.  But I can't get it to work when a textbox is rendered by razor.